# MSVC error when using capture-less lambda expressions as second and third operand of conditional operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, language-lawyer

The code below is happily accepted by both GCC and Clang with `-std=c++14` but causes a compile error with Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto increasing = [](int lhs, int rhs){return lhs < rhs;};
    auto decreasing = [](int lhs, int rhs){return lhs > rhs;};
    std::vector<int> v(0, 10);
    bool increase = true;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), increase ? increasing : decreasing);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

`main.cpp(11): error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'main::<lambda_0228ee097b83254cfd8aa5f4015a245b>' to 'main::<lambda_cb3b816d067baa9d4462132ee332363c>'
main.cpp(11): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called`

I guess my question is which compiler is compliant here, I am guessing that it is not MSVC, and is there a part of the standard which explicitly deals with this situation?

Comment: Please make sure to file a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour When I try to I get "You are not authorized to submit the feedback for this connection." so I guess I'm not allowed to report bugs.

Comment: Hmmm, it was a while ago when I created my connect account, I don't think I had to do anything special to be able to report bugs.

Comment: I filed a bug report for this, wish I had a way to confirm with newer versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have Visual Studio Community 2017, It displays an error (more than one definition for the operator is available), but it runs just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since neither lambda capture they can be converted to function pointers with compatible signatures, so `gcc` and `clang` are correct here.

There is a gcc bug report which summarizes this topic well:  [[c++ lambda] error in assigning lambda expr though "operator?:" while capturing](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54557)  that covers this and says:

> The compiler behaviour looks correct to me. The difference of the
>   lambda expressions in bar and `foo3` compared to the other two is that
>   these are capture-free lambdas and thus have a conversion function to
>   function pointer.
>
> Each lambda expression corresponds to a unique class type, so what we
>   have in `foo1` and `foo2` can be compared with the following
>   class-example:
>
> ```
> struct A{}; struct B{};
> void f() { false ? A() : B(); }
> ```
>
> This expression has no common type for the conditional operator and is
>   ill-formed.
>
> What we have in `bar` and `foo3` can be compared with the following
>   class-example :
>
> ```
> struct A
> {
>     typedef void (*F)();
>     operator F();
> };
>
> struct B
> {
>     typedef void (*F)();
>     operator F();
> };
>
> void f() { false ? A() : B(); }
> ```
>
> This is well-formed, because in the last step of the conditional
>   operator conversion attempts (5.16p5), more general conversions are
>   attempted and these find the common pointer to function.

`5.16p5` says:

> Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands
>   do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified)
>   class type, overload resolution is used to determine the conversions
>   (if any) to be applied to the operands (13.3.1.2, 13.6). If the
>   overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the
>   conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands
>   are used in place of the original operands for the remainder of this
>   section.

If we change your code as follows:

```
int x = 20 ;
auto increasing = [&x](int lhs, int rhs){return lhs < rhs;};
auto decreasing = [&x](int lhs, int rhs){return lhs > rhs;};
```

both `gcc` and `clang` generate an error, `clang` says (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dA32fxH2qly9pL98)*):

```
error: incompatible operand types ('(lambda at prog.cc:8:23)' and '(lambda at prog.cc:9:23)')
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), increase ? increasing : decreasing);
                                      ^ ~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~
```

For reference the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) `5.1.2` *[expr.prim.lambda]* says:

> The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a
>   public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer
>   to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure
>   type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion
>   function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has
>   the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

The wording is modified in the draft C++14 standard but does not alter this property.

**Update**

Filed a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1147028).

Comment: It's a little weird that Clang accept the code even with "-std=c++11". I do think it shouldn't as convert lambda with no capture to function pointer is C++14 standard.

Comment: @Windoze From the C++11 "International Standard" document: *"The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const
conversion function to pointer to function [...]"*

Comment: @Windoze I added the standard reference for this conversion to my answer.