# Using lambda as parameter to std::cout

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am experimenting with lambda use and when testing the following it compile say 'hi'.

```
auto lmda = [](std::ostream& os) -> std::ostream& { os << "hi"; return os; };
std::cout << lmda;
```

But when adding capture, it does not compile.
Example:

```
std::vector<int> v(5, 3);
auto lmda = [&v](std::ostream& os) -> std::ostream& { os << v.size(); return os; };
std::cout << lmda;
```

Build error is:

```
In function 'int main()':
10:18: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
             from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = main()::<lambda(std::ostream&)>]'
 operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

I don't get why it fails in the second example.
Any lead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lambda [without a capture is convertible to a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28746744/1708801) which will match the [following overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```
basic_ostream& operator<<(
std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

As the cppreference links notes:

> Calls func(*this);. These overloads are used to implement output I/O
>   manipulators such as std::endl.

from the draft C++11 standard section `5.1.2` *[expr.prim.lambda]*:

> The closure type for a lambda-expression **with no lambda-capture has a
>   public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer
>   to function** having the same parameter and return types as the closure
>   type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion
>   function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has
>   the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator

Comment: Note: this overload exists so that manipulators like `std::endl` and `std::boolalpha` work. They could've just been `struct`s with overloaded `<<` operators but hindsight.

Comment: @Simple good point, that was noted in the cppreference link I included but added it the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A lambda with no capture is convertible to a pointer-to-function.

> [5.1.2/6] The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function with C ++ language linkage (7.5) having the same
>   parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure
>   type’s function call operator.

A lambda with capture is not convertible to anything printable.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a function that accepts a *stream*, uses it and then return the same stream.

A possible use of it follows:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(5, 3);
    auto lmda = [&v](std::ostream& os) -> std::ostream& { os << v.size(); return os; };
    lmda(std::cout) << std::endl;
}
```