# Trouble using lambda function as function pointer in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to create the following class that I can use to test objects to see if they pass some filter.

```
template <typename T>
class Filter
{
public:
  typedef bool (*Functor)(const T&);

  bool test(const T& t) {
    return func(t);
  }

  void setTester(Functor f) {
    func = f;
  }

private:
  Functor func;
};
```

If I just create a method in the global namespace this works fine.

```
bool testFunc(const Object& obj)
{
  return !obj.name().isEmpty();
}

void foo(const Object& obj)
{
  Filter<Object> filter;
  filter.setTester(testFunc);
  filter.test(obj);
}
```

But what I'd really like is to use lambda functions so that I don't have to create all of my filter methods like this.  I want to be able to create them on the fly.

```
void foo(const Object& object)
{
  Filter<Object> filter;

  filter.setTester([](const Object& object) {
    return !object.name().isEmpty();
  });

  filter.test(object);
}
```

But when I do this I get the following compile error.

```
C2664: 'ov::Filter<T>::setTester' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ov::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda0>' to 'bool (__cdecl *)(const T &)'
with
[
    T=ov::Object
]
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

I've read other posts about passing lambda functions as function pointers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer) and I understand that they cannot capture in order for this to work.  That's fine, and you can see I'm not trying to capture anything.

I am compiling my code using VS2010.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've gotten around this in the past by making the method a template so that it derives the type for me, but I can't do that in this case because I'm copying the function pointer to a member variable to use later.

Comment: Have a look at [std::function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/)

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I cannot reproduce. Are you sure your lambda isn't capturing something?

Comment: Works fine for me http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f488aa72edf6f941

Comment: Have you tried to use + before your lambda ? like : `+[](){}` to force the degradation to a function pointer : example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a9559bf5b56637d

Comment: What compiler are you using?  What are the flags being passed to it?  What is the type of `object.name().isEmpty()`?

Comment: I'm using VS2010 and that appears to be the problem. =\

Comment: @Moohasha I am surprised VS2010 supports lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler likely doesn't support this. You're using MS, so a lot of these things will be missing. They got most the important stuff in the more recent ones, but go back even a little and lots is missing. I don't think they support this even now.

Comment: Converting a lambda to a function pointer is something that works in at least some versions of MSVC compilers...  I think there might have been a bug in a pre-release 2015 compiler, but even that should work with an implicit conversion.

Comment: You're right.  I'm using VS 2010.  If I try to build it in VS 2015 then it compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me, but provided that the class Object is actually defined somewhere, with a member name() returning a string, in which case I use `empty()` instead of `isEmpty()`.

I successfully tested the following code:

```
// class Filter: no modification
class Object { public:string name() const { return "name"; } };

bool foo(const Object& obj)
{ Filter<Object> filter;
  filter.setTester([](const Object& obj) { return !obj.name().empty();});
  return filter.test(obj);
}
int main()
{ Object c; cout << foo(c); 
  system("pause");
}
```

Ouput: 1

p.s: i am using VS2015.

Comment: It appears to be a compiler issue.  When I switched to VS2015 it compiled just fine, but I'm currently using VS2010 so I guess it's not supported.

Comment: @Moohasha That is highly likely. AFAIK VS2010 is not fully compatible with C++11 and there are a few patches to istall, so this shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you explicitly set the output type?

```
filter.setTester([](const Object& object) -> bool {
  return !object.name().isEmpty();
});
```

Comment: Heh, I think this might be the problem; except, shouldn't `!` return `bool`?

Comment: `!` returns `bool` only if the object it is applied to does not overload it. In this case the compiler would have to infer that for every `object` you pass to the function the method `isEmpty()` of the object returned by its method `name()` does not overload the operator. Hard to understand, no?

Comment: No, the compiler just has to check the specific types in play.  The return value of that lambda is `std::decay_t< decltype( !std::declval<Object const&>().name().isEmpty() ) >`.  Once determined, that is fixed. Then it is passed to `setTester`, and the overload to convert-to-function should be found.  This fails to work if *with the actual types*, `!blah` isn't exactly `bool`.  But if `name()` is a `CString` (as it appears to be), `isEmpty()` returns `BOOL`, and `!` would convert to `bool`.

Comment: We don't have the code for `Object`... so we cannot tell many thing about `name()`. Ask the OP to give us details about that class.