# Using member function as a callback

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to pass the method `Connection::onWebSocketEvent` as an argument to `this->ws.onEvent()`, but it doesn't work. I'm new to C++. What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
void Connection::connect(String host, int port, String fingerprint, String token) {
  Serial.println(String("Connect to wss://")+host+":"+port+" with token "+token);
  this->host = host;
  this->port = port;
  this->fingerprint = fingerprint;
  this->token = token;

  this->ws.protocol = "io-json-v1";
  this->ws.beginSSL(this->host, this->port, "/channel", this->fingerprint);

// attempt 1
//  this->ws.onEvent(std::bind(&Connection::onWebSocketEvent, this));

// attempt 2
  this->ws.onEvent([&](WStype_t type, uint8_t* payload, size_t length) {
    this->onWebSocketEvent(type, payload, length);
  });
}

void Connection::onWebSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t* payload, size_t length) {
  // ...
}
```

The method header for `WebSocketsClient::onEvent` is:

```cpp
typedef void (*WebSocketClientEvent)(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length);
void onEvent(WebSocketClientEvent cbEvent);
```

On my first attempt I get this error:

```
IO.cpp: In member function 'void Connection::connect(String, int, String, String)':
IO.cpp:16: error: no matching function for call to 'WebSocketsClient::onEvent(std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Connection::*)(WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int), Connection* const>::type)'
   this->ws.onEvent(std::bind(&Connection::onWebSocketEvent, this));
                                                                  ^
IO.cpp:16:66: note: candidate is:
In file included from IO.h:7:0,
                 from IO.cpp:1:
/Users/chris/Documents/Arduino/libraries/arduinoWebSockets/src/WebSocketsClient.h:50:14: note: void WebSocketsClient::onEvent(WebSocketsClient::WebSocketClientEvent)
         void onEvent(WebSocketClientEvent cbEvent);
              ^
/Users/chris/Documents/Arduino/libraries/arduinoWebSockets/src/WebSocketsClient.h:50:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Connection::*)(WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int), Connection* const>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<void (Connection::*)(WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>(Connection*)>}' to 'WebSocketsClient::WebSocketClientEvent {aka void (*)(WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int)}'
no matching function for call to 'WebSocketsClient::onEvent(std::_Bind_helper<false, void (Connection::*)(WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int), Connection* const>::type)'
```

On the second:

```
IO.cpp: In member function 'void Connection::connect(String, int, String, String)':
IO.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to 'WebSocketsClient::onEvent(Connection::connect(String, int, String, String)::__lambda0)'
   });
    ^
IO.cpp:20:4: note: candidate is:
In file included from IO.h:7:0,
                 from IO.cpp:1:
/Users/chris/Documents/Arduino/libraries/arduinoWebSockets/src/WebSocketsClient.h:50:14: note: void WebSocketsClient::onEvent(WebSocketsClient::WebSocketClientEvent)
         void onEvent(WebSocketClientEvent cbEvent);
              ^
/Users/chris/Documents/Arduino/libraries/arduinoWebSockets/src/WebSocketsClient.h:50:14: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Connection::connect(String, int, String, String)::__lambda0' to 'WebSocketsClient::WebSocketClientEvent {aka void (*)(WStype_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int)}'
no matching function for call to 'WebSocketsClient::onEvent(Connection::connect(String, int, String, String)::__lambda0)'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing lambda as function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer)

Comment: Can you possibly change the function signature of `onEvent`? Otherwise you are probably out of luck if you need a dynamic number of instances.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a pointer to member function as a simple pointer to function argument since a pointer to member function requires the callback to be called on a valid class instance.

The argument type

```
void(*)(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length)
```

does not permit

```
void (Connection::*)(WStype_t type, uint8_t* payload, size_t length)
```

which is the type of a pointer to `Connection::onWebSocketEvent` and a lambda cannot convert to a function pointer unless it does not capture anything.

The trouble here is that you'd get some kind of a circular dependency between the type of `ws` and `Connection` and things start to get uneasy, if you want the type of `ws` to be aware of the current `Connection` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
```

...

```
this->ws.onEvent(std::bind(&Connection::onWebSocketEvent, this, _1, _2, _3))
```