# gcc: Compiling Qt code with lambda function

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, compiler-errors

I have got this piece of code with a lambda function:

```
QMenu menu(this);
menu.addAction("Set file", this, [this, i](){this->setFile(i);});
```

where `setFile(int i)` is a void method defined in the `MyMainWindow` class.

It works when compiling with MSVC2015, but not with gcc 4:4.9.2-2, which gives this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'QMenu::addAction(const char
>   [6], MyMainWindow*, MyMainWindow::eventFilter(QObject*,
>   QEvent*)::)'
>                        menu.addAction("Set file", this, this, i{this->setFile(i);});

My qmake file contains:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

and I have also tried adding:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

But that did not solve the issue. How can I compile this code?

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer). You cannot cast a capturing lambda to a function pointer

Comment: @Rakete1111 `QMenu::addAction` doesn't accept a function pointer.

Comment: @n.m. [It does, sort of](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-4)

Comment: Make sure you are using the same Qt version.

Comment: @Rakete1111 It is a template (the documentation is misleading).