# Why does a lambda convert to a bool whose value is true?

Tags: c++, lambda, boolean, language-lawyer

```
#include <iostream>

void IsTrue(const bool value) {
  if (value) {
    std::cout << "value is True!\n";
  }
}

int main()
{
  IsTrue([]() { ; /* some lambda */ });

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value is True!
```

Why does the lambda evaluate to `true` on GCC & Clang? MSVC cannot build this (cannot convert lambda to bool).

Is it a compiler bug? Or which paragraph of the standard allows this?

Comment: Not sure if this is legal or not but it appears to be converting the lambda into a function pointer and then using that value (which is not null) into the bool so it compiles.  If you add a capture [it fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f28beac0173e86e4).

Comment: MSVC has [a nonstandard extension](https://adishavit.github.io/2016/magical-captureless-lambdas/), so it requires you to explicitly spell out the destination function pointer type, otherwise the conversion will fail.

Comment: Also see [Passing lambda as function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28746744/1708801)

Comment: @NathanOliver yes it is legal see [\[conv.bool\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.bool)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The C++14 standard (*§5.1.2*) says:

> **The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with no**
>   **lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion**
>   **function to pointer to function** with C++ language linkage (7.5)
>   having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s
>   function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function
>   shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has the same
>   effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

Since a function pointer is implicitly convertible to `bool`, you get the result you have shown. This is perfectly legal.

MSVC doesn't compile this because this conversion operator is overloaded with different calling conventions (`__stdcall`, `__cdecl`, etc).
When compiling for `x64` all those calling conventions are not used, so there's just one conversion operator and it compiles fine.