# Does C++ guarantee the lambda unnamed class always has an "operator bool()" defined?

Tags: c++, lambda, operator-overloading, c++14, standards

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    auto f = [] {};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(!f), bool>); // ok

    f.operator bool(); // error: ‘struct main()::<lambda()>’ 
                       // has no member named ‘operator bool’
}
```

Does C++ guarantee the lambda unnamed class always has an `operator bool()` defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) doesn't have `operator bool()`.

`!f` works because lambdas without captures could convert to function pointer (which have a conversion operator for it), and then could convert to `bool`, with the value `true` since the pointer is not null.

On the other hand,

```
int x;
auto f = [x] {};
!f; // not work; lambdas with captures can't convert to function pointer (and bool)
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720989/why-does-a-lambda-convert-to-a-bool-whose-value-is-true