# Passing class member pointer to Lambda capture-list c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I try to pass member pointer to C++11 lambda without success

`pHub` is the member pointer

I keep getting the following error

```
error C2664: 'void Timer::start(void (__cdecl *)(Timer *),int,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Scheduler::start::<lambda_292d45d0b31426827abd837d93b45bff>' to 'void (__cdecl *)(Timer *)'
```

I want to be able to use `pHub` inside the function

```
  pTimer = new Timer(pHub->getLoop());
        pTimer->start([this](Timer *tick) {
            uv_update_time(pHub->getLoop());
            start_time = uv_now(pHub->getLoop());
            printf("Im Tick\n");
        }, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: Only captureless lambdas can be converted to function pointers.

Comment: what does it means

Comment: You should post the definition of `Timer`, at least the relevant part, if you want to get help on making it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not from creating the lambda; it's from trying to pass the lambda to `Timer::start()`.

`Timer::start()` is expecting an argument of type `void (__cdecl *)(Timer *)` -- that is, a plain function pointer. Because you're trying to capture some data (`[this]`), your lambda expression is creating a functor (a callable object).

Think about it: `Timer::start()`'s function pointer argument is going to get passed *a single pointer* (which it expects to point to an appropriate function). There's no place for any additional data (`this`, the address of a functor, etc.) to be passed along. (This is why callback code in C typically has a callback data argument along with a function pointer.)

More comprehensive answer: [Passing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer)

Comment: I don't understand how someone can upvote this answer. It contains a lot of errors.