# How to pass parameter to another function which is being called as argument

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, function-call

I have a function as shown below:

```
bool setJavaScript(int time , const str::string text)
{

d->setJavaTimeOut(time, &shouldTerminate);

}
```

...and the function `shouldTerminate` is like this :

```
bool shouldTerminate(JSContextRef ctx, void* context)
{

}
```

Now, I want the variable `text` in `setJavaScript` to be accessed in `shouldTerminate`, how do I do that?

Both functions are in same file.

The variable `text` has been sent by another function from different file.

Comment: Use a global variable visible from both functions. Utilize `extern` if needed.

Comment: You may pass "text" as a parameter to setJavaTimeOut also, which you may pass to shouldTerminate. You have to change the signature of setJavaTimeOut though.

Comment: Could it make sense to make both functions be methods of a class?

Comment: How do you set context to be passed to the  shouldTerminate?

Comment: Is the text a compile time constant? If not, then are you able to modify d and store text in the context? If you have to bypass the backend entirely, I tried passing a lambda which captures text, but you can't convert that to a function pointer (because where is it stored? what is the lifetime of the capture?) ... but you could possibly achieve it with std::function as recommended in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer