# How to call a function with a reference lambda function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lambda

Code:

```
typedef void(*callbackType) (int);

callbackType globalCallback;

void setit(callbackType callback) {
  globalCallback = callback;
}

int main() {
  int localVar = 5;
  setit([](int num) {
    std::cout << localVar; // there is an error here
  });
}
```

I need to use localVar in lambda function that i send to **setit**

I guess i have to use **[&]{ }**

But how can i do it? How should i declare **setit** and **globalCallback**?

Comment: Capturing lambdas won't convert to function pointers. Use `std::function` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems with the code above.

If you didn't need to capture anything, you could use `+` with lambda to convert it to a function pointer:

```
typedef void(*callbackType)(int);

callbackType globalCallback;

void setit(callbackType callback) {
  globalCallback = callback;
}

int main() {
  setit(+[](int){});
}
```

But this trick works with *capturless* lambdas only.

One possible solution is to change `callbackType` and use `std::function` instead:

```
using callbackType = std::function<void(int)>;

callbackType globalCallback;

void setit(callbackType callback) {
  globalCallback = callback;
}

int main() {
    int localVar = 5;

    setit([localVar](int num) {
        std::cout << localVar; // there is an error here
    });
}
```

which works well.

Comment: What's the `+` for?  5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]: "lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator" https://stackoverflow.com/a/28746827/8918119

Comment: Is it ok to use std::function? Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28746827 dude said that std::function is heavy weight. Is there another way?

Comment: @LightAlex - You are already to the point of optimizing your code? Focus on correctness first.

Comment: @A.A - The `+` is to explicitly cause a coercion to a pointer type.

Comment: @LightAlex "Heavy weight" as in it is what a lot of other languages do implicitly and regularly, but not so much in C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller - i'm writing a https request class. It's ready, but i detected a promblem with using callbacks. The point for the class is max speed.