# Copying c++ lambda to Function Pointer reference

Tags: c++, lambda, scope, reference, function-pointers

I am not sure if I have defined behaviour in the following situation:

My Function pointer type:

```
typedef void (*DoAfter_cb_type)(void);
```

The Function which should assign callbacks:

```
void DoSomething(DoAfter_cb_type & DoAfter_cb)
{
    //...
    DoAfter_cb =  [](){
        //...
    };
}
```

Caller:

```
DoAfter_cb_type DoAfter_cb = nullptr;

DoSomething(DoAfter_cb);

// Here is something that has to be done after DoSomething but before DoAfter_cb.

if( DoAfter_cb != nullptr){
    DoAfter_cb();
}
```

As I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer) lambdas can be implicitly converted to function pointers.

However thoose are still pointers and I fear that something important for calling the lambda is stored on stack and would be out of scope if I just return the function pointer

I have to use function pointers because i do not have access to std::function in my environment.
With std::function I would expect the lambda object to be stored in the reference variable and I would not have any problems.

Is the behaviour the same as If I would just define an ordinary function or do I have any side effects here?

Comment: Didn't Boost have `boost::function<>` ? IIRC C++11 got it from there.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use boost too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the behaviour the same as If I would just define an ordinary function or do I have any side effects here?

Yes, it's the same. A captureless lambda is convertible to a regular function pointer because, to quote the C++ standard ([[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#closure-6), emphasis mine):

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with no
>   lambda-capture has a conversion function to pointer to function with
>   C++ language linkage having the same parameter and return types as the
>   closure type's function call operator. The conversion is to “pointer
>   to noexcept function” if the function call operator has a non-throwing
>   exception specification. **The value returned by this conversion
>   function is the address of a function F that, when invoked, has the
>   same effect as invoking the closure type's function call operator.**

So while the lambda goes out of scope, that pointer is backed by a proper function, just as if you had written it yourself at file scope. Functions "live" throughout the entire execution of the program, so the pointer will be valid, always.

Comment: How to understand the said "**non-generic** lambda-expression"? What are the differences between "non-generic lambda" and "generic lambda"?