# Default argument for a vector of comparator functions

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, function-pointers, comparator

**Function of interest**

I am trying to write a templated `sortDifferentWays` function that will sort (and print) a vector following instructions of a comparator function. I am not sure what is the standard ways to indicate comparators but I went with

```
template<typename T>
void sortDifferentWays(std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<bool (*)(T,T)> comparators)
{
    for (auto& comparator : comparators)
    {
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparator);
        printVec(v);
    }
}
```

**Example of implementation**

The function can for example be implemented in the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class X
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;

    X (int A, int B)
    : a(A), b(B)
    {}

    std::string toString()
    {
        return "{"+std::to_string(a)+","+std::to_string(b)+"}";
    }
};

void printVec(std::vector<int> v)
{
    for (auto& elem : v)
        std::cout << elem <<" ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void printVec(std::vector<X> v)
{
    for (auto& elem : v)
        std::cout << elem.toString() <<" ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

bool compare_a(X left, X right)
{
    return left.a < right.a;
}

bool compare_b(X left, X right)
{
    return left.b < right.b;
}

template<typename T>
void sortDifferentWays(std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<bool (*)(T,T)> comparators)
{
    for (auto& comparator : comparators)
    {
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparator);
        printVec(v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> v = {{1,5},{4,4},{9,2},{4,4},{0,6},{12,2},{11,9}};
    sortDifferentWays(v, {&compare_a, &compare_b});

    return 0;
}
```

, which outputs

```
{0,6} {1,5} {4,4} {4,4} {9,2} {11,9} {12,2} 
{9,2} {12,2} {4,4} {4,4} {1,5} {0,6} {11,9}
```

as expected. I welcome advice as to how improve this function but my main question is the following.

**Question**

I would now like `sortDifferentWays` to have a default `comparators` argument containing a single function which will work well with most (maybe all) primitive types.

```
template<typename T>
void sortDifferentWays(std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<bool (*)(T,T)> comparators = {[](const T& left, const T& right) -> bool{return left < right;}})
{
    for (auto& comparator : comparators)
    {
        std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparator);
        printVec(v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> v = {{1,5},{4,4},{9,2},{4,4},{0,6},{12,2},{11,9}};
    sortDifferentWays(v, {&compare_a, &compare_b});

    std::vector<int> v2 = {4,5,8,3,9,10,2};
    sortDifferentWays(v2);

    return 0;
}
```

But it fails to compile with error message

```
test.cpp:47:70: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<bool (*)(int, int)>'
void sortDifferentWays(std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<bool (*)(T,T)> comparators = {[](const T& left, const T& right) -> bool{return left < right;}})
```

I tried defining a `defaultComparator` as

```
template<typename T>
bool defaultComparator(const T& left, const T& right)
{
    return left < right;
}
```

and give `comparators = {&defaultComparator}` but it did not work either and produced the error message

```
error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?
```

How can I make a default comparator?

**EDIT**

I am compiling with

```
g++ test.cpp -o a -std=c++11
```

where `g++` is defaulted to clang (MAC OSX)

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: are you sure that `sortDifferentWays(v)` is with `v` instead of `V`

Comment: Oops! That's a small typo. Fixed now. It explains many of the compilation error I failed to understand though. Thank you!

Comment: For the others, see my reply

Comment: Why? Why not just use `std::sort` with a custom comparison function/lambda? That's like one or two lines of code, whereas your solution is a ton of code to read through for no obvious gain..

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I cannot reproduce with gcc or clang.

Comment: @JesperJuhl My difficulty is in passing the function as aurgment and in defining a default.

Comment: @Holt I use `g++` which defaults to `clang` (MAC OS).

Comment: @Remi.b What happens in you force the conversion to function pointer by adding a `+` before `[]`?

Comment: @Hold Still the same error message.

Comment: @Remi.b I have clang clang-902.0.39.2 on MacOS and the code compiles fine (even without the `+`). Are you sure that this code triggers the error?

Comment: @Holt Yes I am sure. I have tried with another machine that has clang `clang-700.1.81` and it does not work either. I have a hard time to update to version `902.0.39.2` though. That's weird. Are you sure it works for you after overwriting the functions `sortDifferentWays` and `main` from **Example of implementation** with the ones from **Question**?

Comment: @Remi.b This is the exact code I tested: https://godbolt.org/g/GXME93

Comment: Ah indeed that works :) But it breaks if we add `std::vector<int> v2 = {4,5,8,3,9,10,2};sortDifferentWays(v2);` in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems in this example, however, the one you are searching for has to do with argument `comparators`.

This has been defined as `std::vector<bool (*)(T,T)>`, which is a vector of function pointers. However, you try to initalize it with `{[](const T& left, const T& right) -> bool{return left < right;}}`. This is an initializer_list of lambdas, which is not convertible.

The reason behind this, is that lambdas are a fast way of writing a class with `operator()` overloaded.

```
class lambda
{
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    auto operator()(const T1 &left, const T2 &right) const -> bool { return left < right; }
};
```

Obviously, this class ain't convertible to a function pointer.
In order to handle both function pointers and classes (aka functors), you better use the type `std::function` from `<functional>`. In your case `std::function<bool(T,T)>`.

**Edit**
Monkey0506 indicated that lambdas can be converted to function pointers in case there is no capture and they have the same signature. This last one isn't the case as the arguments of the lambda are const references.

Comment: I am not used to using `std::function`. It'd be great if you could suggest a way to implement it for `sortDifferentWays`?

Comment: Changing `std::vector<bool (*)(T,T)>` to `std::vector<std::function<bool(T,T)>>` should be sufficient from what I tested

Comment: A non-capturing lambda [*should* be convertible to a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer).

Comment: I did not knew that and would not recommend it. Although in this case the argument ain't the same.

Comment: @JVApen Lots of people would recommend against `std::function` due to their overload, which may have some impact here since it's used as a comparator function in `std::sort`.

Comment: @JVApen Your edit is wrong (or at least misleading) - This lambda is capture-less, the capture list is empty (`[]`). The fact that arguments of the lambda are taken as (const)-references does not impact this.

Comment: Tnx, I've fixed it