# How to store methods as function pointers in a map container?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I want to be able to call functions based on the data I read from file.
So for each item type, I want to call the desired reader method.
I wrote this code, but it does not compile where I want to add function pointers to the map. What is wrong?

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
class reader
{

  std::map< std::string, void(*)()> functionCallMap; // function pointer
  void readA(){ std::cout << "reading A\n";};
  void readB(){ std::cout << "reading B\n";};;
public:
  reader()
  {
    *functionCallMap["A"] = &reader::readA;*
    *functionCallMap["B"] = &reader::readB;*
  }

  void read()
  {
   auto (*f) = functionCallMap["A"];
   (*f)();
  }



};
```

I am filling the map at Constructor.

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a member function. The big difference is that member functions needs objects to be called on. You can solve it by using [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead, together with either [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) or [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `std::function` with a lambda or `std::bind` :

```
class reader
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> functionCallMap;

    void readA() { std::cout << "reading A\n"; };
    void readB() { std::cout << "reading B\n"; };

public:
    reader()
    {
        functionCallMap["A"] = [this]() { readA(); };
        functionCallMap["B"] = std::bind(&reader::readB, this);
    }

    void read()
    {
        functionCallMap["A"]();
        functionCallMap["B"]();
    }
};
```

Comment: I prefer your solution because it's more C++ish and cleaner than raw function pointer. Anyway lamba should be preferred to std::bind (Scott Meyer's  Effective Modern C++)

Comment: Yes, It is  a nice solution. But, according to Jason Turner, bind is expensive both in compile time and memory usage.

Comment: @RingZero You should still use std::function instead of a function pointer, I would strongly advise switching the marked answer to this one for future readers.  Using actual function pointers is bad for a number of reasons, but one issue is that you can't bind to anything [*that is a lambda pointer with variable capture*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer).  You will notice that std::function doesn't need the class pointer in the signature using the above.

Answer (score 19):

You need to use pointers to member functions, like this:

```
class reader
{
    using FuncPtr = void(reader::*)(); // function pointer
    std::map< std::string, FuncPtr> functionCallMap;
    void readA(){ std::cout << "reading A\n"; }
    void readB(){ std::cout << "reading B\n"; }
public:
    reader()
    {
        functionCallMap["A"] = &reader::readA;
        functionCallMap["B"] = &reader::readB;
    }

    void read()
    {
        auto f = functionCallMap["A"];
        (this->*f)();
    }
};

int main()
{
    reader r;
    r.read();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two answers so far, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336958/10532253) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53337149/10532253).

The obvious difference is that one uses `std::function` and other uses function pointers. This is not the important difference!!

The key point is that the member functions are *non-static member functions*. So, they are ***not*** of type `void()`.

They are of type `void(reader::*)()`. Thus, they can be only called if an object of type is reader is given; one can understand this somewhat as a hidden parameter.

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336958/10532253) just fixes the problem by specifying the ***correct*** type. This can be done using function pointers (as presented) *or* using `std::function` (The latter is much more expensive!).

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53337149/10532253) fixes the problem by ***binding*** the function pointer to the particular instance of the class. After binding, the type is then indeed `void()`. This cannot be done using raw function pointers (because they can only point to a function and not an object/function pair!).

Comment: Also note that the timing of the binding is a design choice. I.E. does the application always want to bind the object storing the function pointers or potentially another one?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution. It does the job, but I have some doubts over its aesthetics. Anyway, to sum up, I ended up with this code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class reader
{
    std::map< std::string, std::function<void(std::string tableName)>> functionCallMap; // function pointer
    void readA(const std::string tableName){ std::cout << "reading:" << tableName<< "\n"; }
    void readB(const std::string tableName){ std::cout << "reading:" << tableName <<"\n"; }
public:
    reader()
    {
      functionCallMap["A"] = std::bind(&reader::readA, this, std::placeholders::_1);
      functionCallMap["B"] = std::bind(&reader::readA, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    }

    void read()
    {
      const std::string table_name = "A";
      functionCallMap[table_name](table_name);
    }
};

int main()
{
    reader r;
    r.read();
}
```

I pass the table name to the reader, it is nicely done with the *bind* and *placeholder*.

Comment: You should use string references in your callback functions instead of a copy. And as Moia said, you really should use a lambda instead of `std::bind`. About the aesthetics, I don't understand why you need a map of function since `readA` and `readB` are the same. Moreover `readB` is never used so why don't just put so code of `readA` into `read`?

Comment: @Siliace, It seems lambda and bind has its own pros and cons, read A and read B are going to read different kinds of tables, different formats and invoke different factory methods down the line.