# How to fix : Executing lambda expression using pthread in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, pthreads

I have a main.cpp file where I have the following code

```
paral(start, end, [&](int i){
    C1[i] = A1[i] + B[i];
}, numThreads);`
```

I have `paral` definition in otherfile.cpp, where I have the following code

```
void paral(int start, int end, T &&lambda, int nT){
    pthread_t thread1;
    int status = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,lambda ,1);//Should execute lambda(1)
    lambda(2);//Executed by main thread
    //Code for join and so on
}
```

It says:

> can't covert lambda to (void*)(*)(void *).

I tried to cast and pass the lambda function to pthread but it wasn't helpful.
I want to invoke the lambda function from the created thread as well which I'm unable to do.

Comment: Why not use  C++11 thread support library?

Comment: As the man-page for pthread_create states, the function that you give it (lambda) should take one void-pointer as parameter (not an int as in your case) and the value of this parameter is given as the fourth parameter to pthread_create (your second NULL).

Comment: yeah edited the fourth param to 1 as I need to calculte lambda(1)

Comment: @P0W Should be done using pthread library only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing capturing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer)

Comment: A capturing lambda can't be converted to a function pointer. If you must use pthreads, you also must restructure your code to pass the necessary data to the thread function.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must understand that Lambda is an **object**, that implements `operator()(args...)` member function. In your specific case it is `operator()(int i)`.

In order to execute this lambda two parameters must be passed to the `operator()(int)`:

- Lambda pointer (`this`)
- integer

Address of the lambda is an address to object (i.e. data) rather than address of code.

Thread start function instead is a function that accepts `void*` and returns `void*`. Address of function is an address to machine code.

Therefore, to execute your lambda you should define `void* (void*)` function and pass its address as `start_routine` parameter. The address of lambda you pass as `arg` parameter:

```cpp
template<typename Lambda>
void paral(int start, int end, Lambda&& lambda, int nT){

    struct Args
    {
        int Start;
        int End;
        Lambda& Func;
    };

    // create captureless lambda
    auto threadStart = +[](void* voidArgs) -> void* 
    {
        auto& args = *static_cast<Args*>(voidArgs);

        for(int i = args.Start; i < args.End; ++i)
            args.Func(i);
              
        return nullptr;
    };

    // I create one thread here. You will create more.    
    auto args = Args{start, end, lambda};
    pthread_t handle;
    int rc = pthread_create(&handle, NULL, threadStart, &args);

    if(rc)
        throw std::system_error(
            std::error_code(rc, std::generic_category()), 
            "pthread_create");

    pthread_join(handle, nullptr);
}
```

However in this specific case, you better to use `std::thread` instead of `pthread` library. In such case you code may look like following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

template<typename Func>
void paral(int start, 
           int end, 
           Func &&func, 
           int threads_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
{
    std::atomic_int counter {start};
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    workers.reserve(threads_count);

    for(int i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i) {
        workers.emplace_back([end, &counter, &func] {
            for(int val = counter++; val < end; val = counter++)
                func(val);
        });
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < threads_count; ++i)
        workers[i].join();
}    

int main() {
    int C1[10];
    int A[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int B[10] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 110};
    paral(0, 10, [&](int i){ C1[i] = A[i] + B[i]; });

    for(auto&& v: C1)
        std::cout << v << "\n";
    std::cout << "Done. Bye!" << std::endl;
}
```

There is **important note** though. Your code may may work not as fast as you may expect. It will experience the [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) problem as several threads modify the memory of the same cache line, which will force CPU cores to update their L1 caches every time when memory is updated by another CPU core.

See also:

- [Passing C++ captureless lambda as function pointer to C API](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1188594113/passing-cplusplus-captureless-lambda-as-function-pointer-to-c-api)