# c++ lambda function with default capture type

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am new in c++11 and 14, and I am wondering why in this case

```
auto c1 = (bool (*)(int))[](int y) {
    return y%2 == 0;
};
```

the conversion is successful, but when the lambda function has the default capture type, then the conversion fails?

```
auto c1 = (bool (*)(int))[=](int y) {
    return y%2 == 0;
};
```

Comment: [A capturing lambda cannot decay to a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer)

Comment: `=` is not the "default". If it were, you wouldnt have to write it

Comment: The capture usually are stored inside the lambda object itself. If you convert to a simple function pointer, then you won't be able to keep that state.