# Casting a universal reference to a callable to void pointer and vice versa

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I need to wrap a callback mechanism in a C interface in C++ accepting callables.
In the C interface there is a method to set the callback:

```
void c_set_callback(void(*callback)(void* context), void* context);
```

Here is my attempt to wrap this with a callable:

```
template<typename Function>
void set_callback(Function&& function)
{
    c_set_callback
        ([](void* context)
            {
                (*reinterpret_cast<typename std::decay<Function>::type*>(context))();
            }
        , reinterpret_cast<void*>(&function)
        );
}
```

But I can't figure out the right way of casting the context for the universal reference to "function". With the implementation above I get a segmentation fault when the callable is invoked from within the lambda.

Please see https://onlinegdb.com/r1WeuBz08 for the full code example.

Comment: `&function` is not valid after `set_callback` returns and `function` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [it is legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer) to cast a lambda with no captures to a C-style function pointer, your lambda scope is limited to the call to `c_set_callback`.

My approach would be to call once `c_set_callback` at the very beginning of your program, with a static C function as argument. That function, internally, calls a static `std::function<void()>`, and then make your `set_callback` to just change the static `std::function<void()>`.

Something like

```
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> local_callback;

extern "C" void callback_wrapper(void *) {
    local_callback();
}

template<typename Function>
void set_callback(Function&& function) {
    local_callback = std::forward<Function>(function);
}

int main() {
    c_set_callback(&callback_wrapper, nullptr);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, sure, thanks for pointing the scope issue out. Well the intention was to wrap the C interface in a stateless C++ class, plus in my use case I actually have to support multiple callbacks (which is not visible from my example). I think I will create another question on SO because the question (and title) is pretty different (and unrelated to the current question) then. Thanks a lot to solve the first step!