# parameters in glutdisplayfunc

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have function to draw eclipse :

```
void drawEclipse(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat xrad,GLfloat yrad)
```

When I'm calling `glutDisplayFunc(drawEclipse(10,10,3,3));`

It has compilation error:

> ```
> error: invalid use of void expression
> ```

How can I pass parameter to function inside `glutDisplayFunc`?

And this eclipse drawing function is being called dynamically, with a mouse click.

My updated code:

```
void mouseClicks(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        printf("%s -- %d -- %d\n", "clicked",x,y);

        //Way 1
        glutDisplayFunc[&]() { drawEclipse(x,y,5,5); };

        //Way 2
        auto display = [x,y]() { return drawFilledelipse(x,y,3,3); };
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
   }
}
...
int main(){
...

    glutMouseFunc(mouseClicks);
...
```

Comment: So did you read [the docs](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html)? It wants a function pointer, So what you can do is pass a lambda function of the form `void(*func)(void)`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have read the docs, and read as many answers as possible in this and some other site, I had read parameters can be passed as string or maybe other method.. I was looking for that kind of hack..

Answer (score 0):

I'll quote the answer to [Passing capturing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer):

> A lambda can only be converted to a function pointer **if it does not capture**, from the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section 5.1.2 [...]

---

You have to options

The argument of [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html) is a function pointer.
You have to implement a function that draws the ellipse and pass a the function pointer to `glutDisplayFunc`:

```cpp
void display()
{
    drawEclipse(10,10,3,3);

    // [...]
}
```

<s>`glutDisplayFunc(drawEclipse(10,10,3,3));`</s>

```cpp
glutDisplayFunc(display);
```

Alternatively you can use a [Lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) **without any capture arguments**:

```cpp
glutDisplayFunc([]()
{
    drawEclipse(10,10,3,3);

    // [...]
});
```