# C++ Member function as a callback

Tags: c++, callback

I'm using a static class called `websocket` which listens on a websocket (hence the name) and calls a callback function once data is received. I created the following declarations

```cpp
typedef int (*cb)(Json::Value &json);

static void websocket::init();
static void websocket::listen(cb callback, const char* address);
```

I also have a class called `app` which should contain the callback as a member function, because it is using a member property connecting to the database:

```cpp
int app::callback(Json::Value& json)
{
    this->db->insert(json);
};
```

I'm calling the `websocket::listen()` function inside `app` like this:

```cpp
void app::start()
{
    websocket::listen(std::mem_fn(&app::callback), this->path);
}
```

I get an error saying
`error: cannot convert 'std::_Mem_fn<int (app::*)(Json::Value&)>' to 'cb' {aka 'int (*)(Json::Value&)'}`. To be able to keep the code as generic as possible so that I can call `websocket::listen();` with other callbacks as well, I don't want to change the cb typedef.
I can also not make `app::callback` static as it requires `this->db`. What is the best way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Given the restrictions you  have placed upon yourself there is no solution. You are going to have to compromise somewhere.

Comment: The simplest compromise would be to change the typedef to use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) `typedef std::function<int(Json::Value &)> cb;`

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with using std::function as the signature. How would I call it from `app::start`?

Comment: Also, is there a design pattern to solve this problem in C++? Should I try to make the db static and not a property of app?

Comment: `websocket::listen([this](Json::Value& json) { return this->callback(json); }, this->path);` (both `this->` might be omitted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- [`std::mem_fn(&app::callback)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) takes an instance of `app` as the first parameter.
- The most idiomatic alternative would be to use a capturing [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) such as

  ```cpp
  [this] (Json::Value& json) { return callback(json); }
  ```

  but [these cannot be converted to function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28746827/1541563), which makes implementing generic containers for storing and dynamically dispatching to them extremely difficult to do.

One possible approach is to amend your `websocket` interface and accept an optional `void*` context parameter like this:

```cpp
using cb = int(*)(Json::Value &json, void* ctx);

static void websocket::listen(cb callback, const char* address, void* ctx = nullptr)
{
    ...
}

int app::callback(Json::Value& json)
{
    return db->insert(json);
}

void app::start()
{
    websocket::listen([] (Json::Value &json, void* ctx) -> int {
        return static_cast<app*>(ctx)->callback(json);
    }, path, this);
}
```

If you prefer more type safety for this erasure, you can consider [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any):

```cpp
using cb = int(*)(Json::Value &json, std::any ctx);

static void websocket::listen(cb callback, const char* address, std::any ctx = {})
{
    ...
}

int app::callback(Json::Value& json)
{
    return db->insert(json);
}

void app::start()
{
    websocket::listen([] (Json::Value &json, const std::any& ctx) -> int {
        return std::any_cast<app*>(ctx)->callback(json);
    }, path, this);
}
```

The [`std::any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) will throw a [`std::bad_any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/bad_any_cast) if `ctx` was empty or storing a pointer that wasn't a type erased `app*`.