# C++ lambda type conversion?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm new to C++. I was messing around with lambdas and gcc compiler threw an error. Can someone kindly explain why it's happening?

Compilable code:

```
int main() {
    int abc= 456;
    int* abc_ptr= &abc;
    auto lambda= [abc_ptr]() { *abc_ptr= 123; };    // Works fine
    lambda();
}
```

This does not work however:

```
int main() {
    int abc= 456;
    int* abc_ptr= &abc;
    void (*lambda)()= [abc_ptr]() { *abc_ptr= 123; };    // error: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'void (*)()' in initializationx86-64 gcc 11.2 #1
    lambda();
}
```

Comment: Only capture-less lambdas can be converted to a pointer to a function.

Comment: To be more specific, a lambda is not really a function in itself. Rather the compiler will create an object of a unique class, with a suitable function-call operator. This object can have a conversion-operator to a pointer to function, but only if the lamda doesn't have any captures (the list inside the `[` and `]`).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28746744/3455688

Comment: Just for completeness, you could assign your lambda to `std::function <void ()>` if that's what you want (so that you can store it in a member variable, for instance).

Comment: @PaulSanders But using std::function generates "much" overhead... if not needed ( because not mixing a lot of different pointer types ) you als can simly write `auto lambd= [](){}:'

Comment: @Klaus Sure, you would only use it when you needed to.