# cannot convert 'LinkedList::filter(void (*)(Node*))::<lambda(Node*)>' to 'void (*)(Node*)'

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Im trying to implement a simple LinkedList class, but this error shows up and I don't understand why.

```
struct Node {
public:
    int val;
    Node* next;
    Node(int v) : val(v), next(nullptr) {}
};

struct LinkedList {
public:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}

    void append(int value) {
        Node* new_node = new Node(value);
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
        } else {
            tail->next = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
        }
    }

    void traverse(void (*callback)(Node* node)) {
        Node* cur = head;
        while (cur != nullptr) {
            callback(cur);
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }

    LinkedList filter(bool (*filter_function)(Node* node)) {
        LinkedList new_list = LinkedList();
        traverse([&](Node* node) { if(filter_function(node)) new_list.append(node->val); });
        return new_list;
    }
};
```

error is in this line

```
traverse([&](Node* node) { if(filter_function(node)) new_list.append(node->val); });

cannot convert 'LinkedList::filter(void (*)(Node*))::<lambda(Node*)>' to 'void (*)(Node*)'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [Passing capturing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer)

Comment: Traverse takes a pointer to a function but you pass a lambda (which are objects by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a capturing lambda is not the same as a function pointer.  Instead, behind the scenes, it is a fully-fledged object (because it has state).

Fortunately, there's an easy fix - you can use the magical powers of [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to abstract away all the messy details.  To do this, all you have to do is `#include <functional>` and change this:

```
void traverse(void (*callback)(Node* node)) {
```

to this:

```
void traverse (std::function <void (Node* node)> callback) {
```

and [you are golden](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ssRTcGz0OWzlFQfc).