# How can I retrieve the return value of pclose when the unique_ptr is destroyed?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

As @user17732522 pointed out that the deleter of `std::unique_ptr` is supposed to be callable with **exactly one pointer** as argument.

How can I retrieve the return value of `pclose` when the unique_ptr is destroyed?

This [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/541h3fWhG) does not compile,

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>

int ExecCmd(const std::string& cmd, std::string& output)
{
    int ret = 0;

    {
        std::unique_ptr<FILE, void(*)(FILE*, int*)> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), [](FILE* file, int* ret_ptr){
                              if(NULL==file)
                              {
                                  *ret_ptr = -1;
                              } 
                              else 
                              {
                                  *ret_ptr = pclose(file);
                              }
                         });
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Whereas this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/sh6MsjE9c) below compiles.

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>

int ExecCmd(const std::string& cmd, std::string& output)
{
    int ret = 0;

    {
        std::unique_ptr<FILE, void(*)(FILE*)> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), [](FILE* file){
                              if(NULL==file)
                              {
                                 
                              } 
                              else 
                              {
                                    pclose(file);
                              }
                         });
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Here is what the compiler complains about the former code snippet:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.3.0/include/c++/11.3.0/memory:76,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.3.0/include/c++/11.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = _IO_FILE; _Dp = void (*)(_IO_FILE*, int*)]':
<source>:20:27:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.3.0/include/c++/11.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:357:63: error: static assertion failed: unique_ptr's deleter must be invocable with a pointer
  357 |         static_assert(__is_invocable<deleter_type&, pointer>::value,
      |                                                               ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.3.0/include/c++/11.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:357:63: note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.3.0/include/c++/11.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:361:24: error: too few arguments to function
  361 |           get_deleter()(std::move(__ptr));
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/9hn7ofT61) to acquire the return value, but it does not compile:

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>

int ExecCmd(const std::string& cmd, std::string& output)
{
    int ret = 0;

    {
        std::unique_ptr<FILE, void(*)(FILE*)> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), [&ret](FILE* file){
                              if(NULL==file)
                              {
                                  ret = -1;
                              } 
                              else 
                              {
                                  ret = pclose(file);
                              }
                         });
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Could anybody shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Even in the second example, you must still call `pclose`.

Comment: @user17732522 *The deleter is supposed to be callable with exactly one pointer as argument. *  Any reference?  ***What do you expect to be passed as second argument?*** I hope to acquaire the return value of `pclose`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I forgot it.

Comment: As for your problem, see e.g. [this `std::unique_ptr` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) Note that the description text says that "[t]he object is disposed of, using a potentially user-supplied deleter by calling `get_deleter()(ptr)`". Which is also shown in the error message.

Comment: @user17732522 Sorry for my poor English. It's hard for me to express freely. Updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you can only provide a [custom deleter which can be callable with exactly one pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as argument, you can not have the lambda with two arguments in it as deleter.

Your lambda with capture will also not work, as [it can not be converted to a pointer to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer) (i.e. only stateless lambdas can be converted to free function pointers type)

---

> How can I retrieve the return value of pclose when the `std::unique_ptr` is destroyed?

Using lambda

```
int ExecCmd(const std::string& cmd, std::string& output)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const auto deleter = [&ret](FILE* file) { ret = file ? pclose(file) : 0; };
    {
        std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(deleter)> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), deleter);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qfo1nnMMP)

Comment: It's a pity that `gcc 4.9` could not compile this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/TdM5a41YG).

Comment: No need for the nullcheck btw, unique_ptr handles it internally.

Comment: @alagner Any reference?

Comment: @John e.g. this one: [If get() == nullptr there are no effects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/%7Eunique_ptr)

Comment: @alagner It's a bad news. If I understand you correctly, the deleter of the `std::unique_ptr<T>` would not be called if the `std::unique_ptr<T>::get()` is `nullptr`, so the `ret` could not be assigned to `-1`(`0` is wrong in the said code snippet). How do you think about it?

Comment: @John simply initialize `ret = -1` instead. It won't be overwritten if the `FILE*` is `nullptr`.

Comment: @John exactly as you've written. Note that it can always be pre-set to -1 or a more complex object can be utilized to monitor the output.

Comment: @alagner ***a more complex object can be utilized to monitor the output.*** How? I really can't see it helps.  As you say the deleter would not be called if `std::unique_ptr<T>::get()` is `nullptr`. Could please explain that in more detail?

Comment: @John for example: the int can be replaced with a wrapper that indicates whether/when it was modified. Difficult to answer without a broader context. If `ExecCmd` is more-less close to the way it's used, I'd just set the integer -1 and don't care too much ;) @JeJo it won't hurt, it's simply superfluous and always false ;)

Comment: @alagner ***a wrapper that indicates whether/when it was modified***, like `std::optional`?

Comment: @John optional is a good example if its operation is what you want. Another option would involve something that would log/crash/do anything else to indicate its value has not been checked when leaving the scope; plenty of options there, but I cannot tell the use case for you :)

Comment: @JeJo Thanks very much. This is the first time I encounter such problem. And It makes dazed that should I never construct lambdas in this way in the future with GCC4.9.3? I created [a new post to make it clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72373561/problem-when-constructing-the-lambdas-with-compiler-of-specific-version).

Answer (score 2):

As you're not using the `output`, it can be removed. You'll need to pass `ret` by reference to the deleter so that it can be modified by the result. Ternary operators can help to reduce `if` blocks as `fp` will evaluate to `false` if it is a null pointer. You can acquire the type of `deleter` with `decltype` so that it can be easily passed to the template of `std::unique_ptr`.

```
int execCmd(const std::string& cmd) {
    int ret{};
    auto deleter = [&ret](FILE* fp) { ret = fp ? pclose(fp) : 0; };
    {
        std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(deleter)> pipe{popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"),
                                                  deleter};
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It's a pity that gcc 4.9 could not compile this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/TdM5a41YG). Do you know why?

Comment: @John If you write the code like this answer and not some fancily modified version of it, it will compile. Hint: use `auto deleter = ...;` instead of `auto deleter{...};`.

Comment: @j6t Yep, thanks a lot. You save me an hour. I really curious why `auto deleter = ...;` works, whereas `auto deleter{...};` does not. Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: @John Compiler bug? It seems to treat the curly braces as `initializer_list` instead of a uniform initialization.

Comment: @jet Thanks a lot. This is the first time I encounter such problem. And It makes dazed that should I never construct lambdas in this way in the future with GCC4.9.3? I created [a new post to make it clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72373561/problem-when-constructing-the-lambdas-with-compiler-of-specific-version).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jelo, @Some programmer dude, @user17732522.

For the readers of this post, [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/ccz7h7ndE) works, too.

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<functional>

using std::placeholders::_1;

void ClosePipe(FILE* file, int& ret)
{
    ret = pclose(file);

    return;
}

int ExecCmd(const std::string& cmd, std::string& output)
{
    int ret = -1;

    auto delete_binded = std::bind(ClosePipe, _1, std::ref(ret));

    {
        std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(delete_binded) > pipe{popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"),  delete_binded};
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for pointing out the error. I will correct it now.