# Problem when constructing the lambdas with compiler of specific version

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Why this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/18EG57ajn) compiles with `GCC 4.9.3`,

```
#include<memory>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>

int ExecCmd(const std::string& cmd, std::string& output)
{
    int ret = 0;

    const auto deleter= [&ret](FILE* file){
                              if(NULL==file)
                              {
                                  ret = -1;
                              } 
                              else 
                              {
                                  ret = pclose(file);
                              }
                            };

    {
        std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(deleter) > pipe{popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"),  deleter};
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{

}
```

whereas [this code snippet](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/79W4h5GPh) does not compile with `GCC 4.9.3`：

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include<cstdio>

int ExecCmd(const std::string& cmd, std::string& )
{
    int ret = 0;
    
    auto deleter{[&ret](FILE* file){
                              if(NULL==file)
                              {
                                  ret = -1;
                              } 
                              else 
                              {
                                  ret = pclose(file);
                              }
                            }
    };
    
    {
        std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(deleter)> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), deleter);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Here is what the compiler complains:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/memory:81:0,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::~unique_ptr() [with _Tp = _IO_FILE; _Dp = std::initializer_list<ExecCmd(const string&, std::string&)::<lambda(FILE*)> >]':
<source>:24:87:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-4.9.3/include/c++/4.9.3/bits/unique_ptr.h:236:16: error: no match for call to '(std::unique_ptr<_IO_FILE, std::initializer_list<ExecCmd(const string&, std::string&)::<lambda(FILE*)> > >::deleter_type {aka std::initializer_list<ExecCmd(const string&, std::string&)::<lambda(FILE*)> >}) (_IO_FILE*&)'
    get_deleter()(__ptr);
                ^
```

Note:

1. I only have to use `GCC 4.9.3`.
2. I always use `auto lambda{[](...){...}}` to construct lambdas. ***This is the first time that I encounter such problem. And It makes dazed that should I never construct lambdas in this way in the future with `GCC4.9.3`?*** Or under what conditions, I should pay attention to such a problem?

Thanks to @J6t, @JeJo. I found how to make the code snippet complies.

I thought and thought, but I still can't find the answer.

Could anybody shed some light on this matter?

Comment: Maybe you could share the error message the compiler writes?

Comment: So, your question is why does `auto deleter = [&..]....` work, but `auto deleter {[&...]....` not? The `const` in the first version does not change anything.

Comment: Looks like the issue isn't necessarily the compiler, but the libstdc++ version in use

Comment: Looks like a problem with the `unique_ptr` implementation in GCC 4.9. It starts working with GCC 5.1. I would suggest to upgrade the compiler.

Comment: The type deduced is initializer list of lambdas instead of a lambda. Not sure if it's a bug in GCC or defect in the language though. Note there have been several ones around brace initialization which were fixed and GCC 4.9 is - least to say - old.

Comment: gcc 4.9.3 has the same issue with the much smaller example `auto x{1}; int y = x;` - `x` is an `initializer_list`, not an `int`. This seems to be a bug in 4.9.3. The solution is to not combine `auto` with a braced initializer. (It's not clear why you would desire to do this with the lambda but not with `ret`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Is this really a bug? It seems that 4.9.3 just does not implement [N3922](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html), which came after C++11. According to [this document](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11), it is a C++17 language future that was implemented in GCC 5.

Comment: @DanielLangr It seems to me that you are 100% correct, and it was a defect in the language, not in gcc. Sufficiently old versions of icc and clang do the same thing.

Comment: @mch Yes.You are right.

Comment: @John OT: Please, format the code better next time. Some people even read SO posts on mobile devices, and you make it harder for them. There are lines with unnecessary curly braces, and the indentation is too large. I personally use only 2-space indentation in SO code.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you have to use such an old GCC version?

Comment: @DanielLangr I would follow your advice about indentation. For the version of the compiler, it's my project decides. I have no choice. :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the second version is that, in C++11 and C++14, the following initialization:

```
auto var{ whatever };
```

yields the type of `var` to be of `std::initializer_list<something>`.

This changed in C++17 which accepted the [N3922 paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html). This paper was adopted by GCC [since version 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). Your 4.9.3 thus deduces `std::initializer_list`, which is not what you want.

---

> I always use `auto lambda{[](...){...}}` to construct lambdas.

Bottom line: Don't do this with GCC 4.9.3.