# C++: "no instance of constructor "std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::tuple [with _T1=void (*)(Effect e), _T2=int]" matches the argument list"

Tags: c++

I can't figure out what the error here means, nor the constructor it would be referencing.

```
void generateEffect(Effect e){
    static const map<string, void (*)(Effect e, vector<variant<int>> setUpData)> dataDict = {
        {
            "String", [](Effect e, vector<variant<int>> setUpData){
            e.data = {0};
            e.onUpdate.push_back(tuple <void (*)(Effect e), int>
            {//<- Error is here
                [&setUpData](Effect e){
                var = get<int>(setUpData[0]);
                }, 1});
            }
        }
    };
};
```

When I change the code to not include the setUpData capture, i.e.

```
e.onUpdate.push_back(tuple <void (*)(Effect e), int>
            {
                [](Effect e){}, 5});
            }
```

the error goes away. What should I do?

Comment: please post a [mre] that we can copy paste in our compilers and see the exact same issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, the only relevant missing part should be 
```
class Effect{
     vector<variant<int>> data;
    vector<tuple <void (*)(Effect e), int>> onUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Capturing lambdas cannot be converted to free function pointers. Use `std::function` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question?: [Passing capturing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28746744/1458097)