# Lambda cannot be passed to templated function which takes a function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, callback, function-pointers

**My Setup**

I have these things setup,

1. A struct
2. A templated function pointer that takes that struct as parameter with T as return type
3. A templated method invoker that takes the callback of the function pointer type with T as return type of the function pointer as well as the method.

```cpp
// Setup

struct SomeParams
{
    const SomeType someData;
};

// Function Pointer
template<typename T>
using FuncCallback = T(__stdcall*)
    (
        SomeParams params
    );

// Method that takes the Function pointer
template<typename T>
T InvokerMethod(FuncCallback<T> callback);
```

**Issue**

When I try to call the InvokerMethod by passing a lambda expression the compiler cries.

```cpp
auto myCallback = [](auto params)
    {
        return params.someData;
    };

SomeType data = ptr->InvokerMethod(myCallback); // Compile Error
```

Compilers tears show this error message:

> Error E0304 - no instance of function template "InvokerMethod" matches the argument list
>
> argument types are: (lambda [](auto params)->auto)

**Works fine with same lambda as STATIC method**

```cpp
// .h
static SomeType GetData(const SomeParams params);

// .cpp
SomeType GetData(const SomeParams params)
{
    return params.someData;
}

SomeType data = ptr->InvokerMethod(GetData);
```

I want to know why there is no error when passing a static method but an error when passing a  lambda.

I might be doing some silly thing as being new to cpp i might be overlooking some key knowledge around this. Please guide me, any help would be great!

I have tried making the lambda also static but doesn't work.

Comment: The standard library itself never use function pointers for functions you pass to it. Instead they use the template type itself. Like e.g. `template<typename F> void foo(F func) { func(); }`. That allows you to pass *any* callable object, including lambdas.

Comment: Lambdas are not functions. `T(__stdcall*)(SomeParams)` can't be deduced from a lambda type.

Comment: Try this `ptr->InvokerMethod(+myCallback)`

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It's unlikely helpful, the lambda is generic with the `auto` parameter.

Comment: @273K right, missed that. but it doesn't need to be generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda can only be converted to a function pointer if it does not capture, see [Passing capturing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer).

In OP's code,

```cpp
auto myCallback = [](auto params)
    {
        return params.someData;
    };
```

The lambda has no capture, so it can decay to function pointer automatically.

**The reason why the code cannot compile is using `auto` in the lambda function.** `SomeType data = ptr->InvokerMethod(myCallback); // Compile Error` cannot deduce the right type to instantiate the template for both lambda and `InvokerMethod`.

Instead, try to explicitly give the type

```cpp
auto data = ptr->InvokerMethod<SomeType>(myCallback);
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/95TP6rn6T for a live demo.

Comment: I guess being fairly new to cpp, 'auto' is a dangerous thing, the demo link also helped to understand how the compiler is generating the templated function behind the scenes