# How to use the correct instance with static inline member pointer and static member function?

Tags: c++, class, callback, c++20, static-members

I have a static callback member function that calls a non-static window procedure member function via a static inline pointer. The problem is, it ends up calling the last instance. Here is an example that demonstrates the core of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    static inline A* pThis;
    int i;     

    A(int i) : i(i) {
        pThis = this;
    }

    static void foo() {
        std::cout << pThis->i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a1(1); 
    A a2(2); 

    a1.foo(); // prints 2 instead of 1
    a2.foo(); // prints 2 as expected

    return 0;
}
```

Note, I cannot change the signature of the callback function, so recommending to make foo accept an argument is futile. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Unrelated: Avoid having pointer/reference members like this. What if the current object gets destroyed and you still use the static method `foo`? You'll then have undefined behavior.

Comment: Each time you're calling `foo` you're updating `pThis` to point to the current object. So the code behaves as expected. This looks more like a design problem than a programming problem.

Comment: Nitpicking: We don't "call an instance", we call a function :)

Comment: But yes, your pointer is `static` (i.e. shared amongst all of your instances), and at each construction, you update it with the last created instance address. Remember that the computer does behave as you want it to but as you tell it to :)

Comment: _"How do I solve this problem?"_ You rewrite your code so that you don't need self-contradictory functions?

Comment: @Fareanor In my project, i cannot register the window if the callback function is not static.

Comment: Then you are asking a XY problem. Do not ask how to finish your attempted solution to a problem, ask about the problem itself. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365798/4832499) for a possible solution.

Comment: Don't use static data,. don't have problems with static data. Easy.

Comment: @machine_1 But your design is flawed to begin with. It's an open door to undefined behaviour if the static function is called before the pointer is initialized (i.e. before an instance is created) or after the last instance is destroyed. I agree it's an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Do this `A::pThis = &a1;` just before callilng `a1.foo();`, and then do `A::pThis = &a2;` just before calling `a2.foo();`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem is, it ends up calling the last instance

Each time you're creating an object using the ctor `A::A(int)` you're updating `pThis` to point to the current/latest instance. Thus when you create `a2` using `A a2(2);`, the `pThis` was updated to point to this new object.

This looks more like a design problem than a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Correct *"static callback member"* have a way to pass extra argument,

The old/C way is generally a `void* userData`.
In C++, `std::function` would be a good alternative, or an "interface".

as `A::foo` is `static`,

`a1.foo();` is actually `a1; A::foo();` so just `A::Foo();`.

Changing the `callback` would be fine.

> I cannot change the signature of the callback function

So, if you want to reset `A::pThis` to "correct" one, you might do it manually:

```
A::pThis = a1;
A::foo();
A::pThis = a2;
A::foo();
```