Converting C++ capturing lambda to function pointer, the generic way
Currently I use the following code to convert a capturing lambda to a function pointer for C-style APIs:
template <typename... T, typename Callable>
auto wrap_closure(const Callable& c) -> void(*)(T...)
{
    static Callable closure = std::move(c);
    return +[](T... data) {
        closure(data...);
    };
}

It can be used like:
  // we have EthernetClient& client reference captured by lambda
  void* s = mz_stream_write_callback_create(
    wrap_closure<const void*, int32_t>(
      [&](const void* buf, int32_t size) -> void {
        while(size > 0) {
          // we're writing without compression, so I expect the file data to come in chunks of HTTP_req array size
          // because this is how we read'em in line 221
          size_t written = client.write((const uint8_t*)buf, std::min(size_t(size), sizeof(HTTP_req)));
          if(!written) {
            break;
          }
          size -= written;
          buf = (const uint8_t*)buf + written;
        }
      }
    )
  );

The only drawback is that I have to type the argument types twice - firstly in the template parameters, then in the lambda itself. Is it possible to deduct template parameters from lambda argument types?

"The only drawback is that ..." - that is not the only drawback. Your use of a local static variable means that calling a specific instantiation of wrap_closure() for a given set of template parameters will only work correctly the 1st time it is called. The variable won't be updated on subsequent calls.

"Is it possible to deduct template parameters from lambda argument types?" - no, because wrap_closure is being passed a lambda object instance, not the operator() of that object. The arguments in question are on the operator where the lambda is invoked by wrap_closure, they are not on the object itself where wrap_closure is being called from.

@RemyLebeau But each lambda will instantiate a different wrap_closure, because each lambda has a different type.

@Yksisarvinen imagine a scenario where wrap_closure is being called in a loop and the loop is defining the lambda. There would be only 1 lambda type but multiple invokations of wrap_closure using separate instances of that same type

What you are trying to do will always have the drawback of making the call non-reentrant. You must store the captures in some memory and if you only have a function pointer, then that must be a fixed hard-coded memory location. It can't be two different ones. That's why lambdas do not provide this functionality. To make what you want work you always need to be able to either pass a pointer and a specific type of the lambda (from which the function address can be figured out) or two pointers: one for the function and one for the captures (that's the C way).

@RemyLebeau what if I rewrite the code as static Callable closure; closure = std::move(c);? Then it will be updated on each invocation of wrap_closure.

@RemyLebeau Ah, I see. It would do a funny every time capture list depends on current invocation (so if you capture this or anything related to loop).

@user17732522 If I understand correctly, it's a problem related more to function pointer callbacks themselves rather than this solution of converting lambdas to function pointers?

No, I am talking generally. Whether you are talking about lambdas or some other callbacks doesn't matter. Your suggested solution, even with the improvement from your comment, still has the same issue: The lambda can't be called recursively (whether directly or indirectly), nor can it be called from two different threads at the same time.

Are you sure the C-style API doesn't have a void* user_data parameter?

In a C-style API the conventional solution to this problem is to provide a second user_data parameter as a void* in the function/struct that retrieves the function pointer and then to have the call site call the function pointer with that pointer as argument. And if you have that API, it can be made to work with a capturing lambda as well.

@NathanOliver your link is about .h or .hpp extension for header files of class definitions. Did you want to paste another link?

@AlexandrZarubkin Woops, copy pasta error.  Correct link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45365798/4342498

@user17732522 @Artyer you're right, I'm sorry. I missed that void* user_data parameter which actually comes first. How would this work with capturing lambda? I'm not sure if I should edit the question.

This can be done by checking the type of &Closure::operator(). You can piggy-back off of the stuff for std::function's existing deduction guides:
template<auto& closure, typename Ret, typename... T>
auto wrap_closure_impl(std::function<Ret(T...)>*) {
    return +[](T... data) -> Ret {
        return closure(data...);
    };
}

template <typename Callable>
auto wrap_closure(const Callable& c)
{
    static Callable closure = std::move(c);

    return wrap_closure_impl<closure>(static_cast<decltype(std::function(closure))*>(nullptr));
}

You could also only name the type in the template arguments and use a generic lambda:
wrap_closure<const void*, int32_t>(
    [&](auto buf, auto size) -> void {
        // ...
    }
)

But do take note of the issues raised in the comments

The first code snippet is C++20, right?

@AlexandrZarubkin It's C++20 because of the lambda template params. You can make it C++17 with a helper function instead of a lambda

I'm sorry, I'm not sure I did that correctly, but my attempt failed to compile. Could you post C++17 version next to C++20?

@AlexandrZarubkin Oh I see it's a little more difficult because of the static variable. I've put a slightly different approach in the answer, but you can more directly translate the C++20 version like this: https://godbolt.org/z/Wea1GdeMW

If the C API has a void* user_data parameter as first parameter, followed by the function pointer parameter, then you can do something like:
auto lambda = [/*captures*/](){ /*...*/ };
c_api(&lambda, +[](void* ptr){ (*static_cast<decltype(lambda)*>(ptr))(); });

Note that c_api will not take ownership of the lambda. You will need to make sure that lambda outlives the pointer passed to c_api. If c_api stores the pointers for a later callback, instead of using them directly in the call, then you need dynamic allocation:
auto lambda = new auto([/*captures*/](){ /*...*/ });
c_api(lambda, +[](void* ptr){ (*static_cast<decltype(lambda)>(ptr))(); });

// delete lambda; where suitable

In that case I would strongly recommend to wrap c_api in a C++ class that implements RAII properly with the help of std::unique_ptr and a destructor that e.g. deregisters the callable from the C API.

Thank you everyone, @RemyLebeau, @NathanOliver, @user17332522, @Artyer and others. I think I've come up with a solution which builds on your input and shared links.
I'm posting it here. I've been able to avoid typing the argument types twice and let the compiler derive them. Some tests included. It works fine if lambda calls itself recursively. Although the wrapper generator is not thread-safe, after the lambda is wrapped, the resulting function pointer can be called from multiple threads. I think it covers quite wide range of use cases.
I'm not very good with templates, so there's certainly room for optimization.
#include <iostream>

template <typename Callable, typename Ret, typename ... Args>
auto wrap_closure_helper(const Callable& l, Ret (Callable::*)(Args...) const) -> Ret(*)(Args...) {
    static Callable local = l; // no default constructor, so we need to initialize it with a value
    // the following emulates a copy assignment operator
    // NOT threadsafe, but it makes wrap_closure work in a loop
    // where it creates a new wrapped instance of the same lambda on each iteration
    using type = decltype(local);
    local.~type(); // lambda's destructor and constructor are non-throwing, I think. Should be safe.
    new (&local) type(l);
    
    return +[](Args... args) {
        return local(args...);
    };
}

template <typename Callable>
auto wrap_closure(const Callable& l)
{
    return wrap_closure_helper(l, &Callable::operator());
}

void c_style_function(int (*f)(int)) {
    std::cout << "f(42) == " << f(42) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  // test wrap_closure with a lambda, simple invocation. It's a simple case, because the lambda does not capture anything.
  std::cout << "Testing wrap_closure with a lambda, simple invocation: [](int x){return x + 1;}" << std::endl;
  c_style_function(wrap_closure([](int x) { return x + 1; }));

  // test wrap_closure with a capturing lambda, simple invocation
  std::cout << "Testing wrap_closure with a capturing lambda, simple invocation: [&y](int x){return x + y;}" << std::endl;
  int y = 10;
  c_style_function(wrap_closure([&y](int x) { return x + y; }));

  // test wrap_closure with a capturing by reference lambda, multiple invocations in a loop
  std::cout << "Testing wrap_closure with a capturing by reference lambda, multiple invocations in a loop" << std::endl;
  for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    c_style_function(wrap_closure([&y](int x) { return x + y; }));
  }
  
  // test wrap_closure with a capturing by value lambda, multiple invocations in a loop
  std::cout << "Testing wrap_closure with a capturing by value lambda, multiple invocations in a loop" << std::endl;
  for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    c_style_function(wrap_closure([y](int x) { return x + y; }));
  }

  // test wrap_closure with a recursive lambda
  std::cout << "Testing wrap_closure with a recursive lambda" << std::endl;
  // should print 955. // 1 + 2 + ... + 42 == (1 + 42) * 42 / 2 == 43 * 21 == 903, 
  // and there are 42 increments of y, so 903 + 42 == 955
  c_style_function(wrap_closure([&y](int x) {
    std::function<int(int)> self = [&](int x) {
      if(x == 0) {
        return y;
      } else {
        ++y;
        return x + self(x - 1);
      }
    };
    return self(x);
  }));

  // test creating two wrapped lambdas with similar signatures at the same time
  std::cout << "Testing creating two wrapped lambdas with similar signatures at the same time" << std::endl;
  auto lambda1 = wrap_closure([](int x) { return x + 1; });
  auto lambda2 = wrap_closure([](int x) { return x + 2; });
  c_style_function(lambda1);
  c_style_function(lambda2);
}

